# error in building transform_graph in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am optimizing my frozen Tensorflow model using `transform_graph` by using this command in bash:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph': no such package 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms': BUILD file not found on package path
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.060s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Tensorflow is installed in PIP library.

When using the Tensorflow tools with bazel, should be installed by Tensorflow source code with bazel.

Then you can use the Tensroflow tools.

Please check the installation and links.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

Comment: Is the Tensorflow i installed using pip different from the Tensorflow I will get when I "install from sources"? If yes, should i uninstall Tensorflow first using pip uninstall?

Comment: In my case, I installed the 1.2 version PIP Tensorflow, and 1.4 version sources Tensroflow. It works well.

Comment: You installed Tensorflow twice, using pip and from sources? I don't get it.

Comment: I install two Tensorflow using virtualenv.

Comment: So do you suggest that I uninstall the Tensorflow I installed using pip? And install from sources instead?

Comment: I think that is the best option to you. This link helps you. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac

Comment: Do I have another choice if I already have installed Tensorflow using pip?

Comment: Oh you can install two Tensorflow's? :O

Comment: Inside the same conda env?

Comment: Sure. In unix and linux system it doesn't conflict. When using the tensorflow in python, python find the PIP library first. But when using bazel in the source tensorflow folder, if you type the configure and build, bazel find the source tensorflow first. Of course conflict occurred between above 1.0 and over 1.0 tensorflow's. But in your case conflict not occurred.

Comment: Hi, you might want to check my other post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309506/how-to-use-transform-graph-to-optimize-tensorflow-model